# Scraping oldschool HTML - Dont think I can use XPath/Dom, and rusty at regexps

Tags: html, dom, preg-match, web-scraping

Here's a snippet of the HTML I'm trying to scrape:

```
    <div class="dot"><hr/></div>





    <h2>Description</h2>












        <p>This is the information I am trying to scrape</p>


</div>
```

I don't think I can use XPath to retrieve the contents of `<p>` as it has no id nor class, and depending on other information above the XPath provided by firebug can be `/html/body/div[3]/div/div[???]/p[2]` - where ??? is a number between 1-5.

If that's right, then I'm guessing its back to a good old regexp (which I'm useless at), and this is unfortunately the best I've come up with to try and catch it:

`preg_match('/<h2>Description<\/h2>\s*<p>(.+)<\/p>/',$html,$rawdesc);`

Of course it doesn't work....or I wouldn't be throwing  myself at your mercies :)

Comment: Why don't you just get all `p` (in a container) and pick the one you need?

Comment: Because the number of `<p>` changes depending on the document being scraped. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Should this question be tagged as php?

Comment: Wouldn't you have the exact same problem when parsing it using regex?

Comment: Not if I used it to match the tail-end of the previous `</h2>` element in addition to the `<p>` I don't think I would?

Comment: So your question basically is how to match an `p` element directly after a `h2` tag? Also what language are yo using, because the implemented `xpath` library may differ

Comment: Yes, but also with an unknown amount of whitespace (tabs, carriage returns) between the two elements. I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath, or similar DOM-parsing libraries, are **always** better than regex for parsing html. There really are no exceptions unless you are looking at an extremely simple single-use case.

If you are looking to match a `p` element directly after a `h2` tag, use an xpath like the following:

```
.//p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h2]]
```

I believe there are simpler xpath queries that one could use, but this is what I have tested and verified to work.

The following code will get you what you need:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourHtmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query('.//p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h2]]');
$result = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Wow I didn't realise you could do this. I'm a big fan of DOM parsing (mainly because my regexp sucks) so I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern works:

```
preg_match('~<h2>Description</h2>\s*<p>\K(?>[^<]++|<++(?!/p>))+~', $html, $rawdesc);
print_r($rawdesc);
```

Yours works too if you add a `?` after the `+`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to first limit the `$html` to the section holding the description, such as

```
$start = strpos($html, '<h2>Description</h2>');
$end = strpos($html, '</div>', $start)
$html = substr($html, $start, $end-$start)
```

Then you can do what PeeHaa suggested and get all `<p>...</p>` using `preg_match_all`. Then use `implode` to merge them. But maybe I didn't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the preg_match itself is the problem, you might also try adding a /s switch to your pattern, i.e. `preg_match('/<h2>Description<\/h2>\s*<p>(.+?)<\/p>/s',$html,$rawdesc);`